# Difference between timer values not as expected

Tags: timer, microcontroller

I'm sorry if this is a basic question.
I am working on an embedded project. Somewhere in the project in some driver files there is a function named _time returnTime() that is said to return a mcu time with a 10 microseconds resolution. I guess it reads the registers for a timer module of the mcu and returns them and this timer has a 10 microseconds resolution.

I also have a user defined function. I want to test how much it takes to execute this function.
So I have decided to use function returnTime for this by calling it before the first and after the last instructions of my function.

In the function that I want to test how long it takes to execute I do something like this:

```
myFunction()   
{
    time1 = returnTime();
      ...
    time2 = returnTime();
    time_elapsed = time2 - time1;
 }
```

When I do this function time_elapsed is a value of 5 and sometimes 4. Is that possible. Since the `returnTime()` function returns a time with 10 microsecond resolution shouldn't time_elapsed also be a value which is a multiple of 10?(like 0, 10, 20,...etc)

Comment: a number of things are going on here.  10ms resolution or accuracy?  is that a generic function that works at all speeds for the mcu even ones where the mcu can have a better accuracy than the worst case?  while using timers to test code is how you do it, not knowing the timer intimately means you wont get good results, most benchmarks fail due to not understanding how the timer is measuring time.  and then fail for other reasons even with a good timer.  so be careful making any judgments on performance based on your experiment.

Comment: It depends. If `returnTime()` is documented to return microseconds, I would expect multiples of 10. But if `returnTime()` returns something like the number of ticks, it's OK to get 4 or 5. What does the documentation say *exactly*?

Comment: what if you have no code in between and call returnTime() many times time1=returnTime(), time2=returnTime(), time3=returnTime() then after several samples display/save those values and view them, are they jumping by 10s?  do you get repeated values, etc?

Comment: for benchmarking like this you want to control time yourself, dont use a function, find a timer that will do the job and use it directly. carefully examine the assembly  output of the compiler to confirm you didnt get any optimizations that mess up your measurement of time, and understand that the same machine code on the same mcu is possible of taking different amounts of time based on certain factors even with good time measurement, depends on the processor/product.

Comment: and the same code/build can possibly vary by a unit of time across different runs that is possible in some cases, impossible in others. this so far is way too broad of a question.

Answer (score 0):

The timer may have a resolution of 10 microseconds but what are the units of the value returned by `returnTime()`?  Perhaps `returnTime()` returns a value with units of "ticks" where one tick is equal to 10 microseconds.  (The hardware timer module typically counts by one tick.)

Let's assume your function takes 42 microseconds to execute.  If the function starts executing one microsecond *before* the next tick of the timer, then the timer will tick five times before the function finishes.  But if the function starts one microsecond *after* the timer ticks, then the timer will tick only four times during the function execution.  So sometimes `returnTime()` will return 5 and sometimes it will return 4.

The above are the simplest explanations.  Also the hardware timer module could be setup incorrectly for the MCU clock speed.  Also, if interrupts are enabled, then an interrupt could be occurring during execution of the function which makes the function execution time appear to vary.